# Estimating distribution of tied ranks for tie correction to Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, bootstrap, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Tests based on ranking elements, such as

> Mann, H. B.; Whitney, D. R. On a Test of Whether one of Two Random Variables is Stochastically Larger than the Other. *Ann. Math. Statist.* 18(1):50-60, 1947, [doi:10.1214/aoms/1177730491](https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177730491),

are particularly useful because the only constraint they place on the underlying distributions is that they are continuous.  The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U test can be extended or corrected to work with discrete distributions containing ties (for which I don't know the citation), but the extensions require you to know something about the underlying distribution.  For example the Wikipedia article on Mann Whitney gives, for large samples, a normal approximation with a [correction factor for the distribution of ties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Normal_approximation_and_tie_correction), where you need to know the exact number of possible ranks, and the relative number of elements in each rank.

Suppose all I have are two small sample sets $R$ and $S$, that may or may not come from the same underlying discrete distribution (and that's what I'm trying to test).  $|R|=5$ and $|S| \approx 50$, so these are quite small.  The only information I have about the underlying distribution is $R$ and $S$, so do I use $R \cup S$ as the underlying distribution?  Or just $R$ when I'm calculating the $U$ statistic for $S$ and just $S$ when I'm calculating the $U$ statistic for $R$?  When calculating the histogram for the $U$ statistic for use in testing the null hypothesis, should I select from $R \cup S$ with or without replacement?  Why?  I'm going to guess with replacement, because that's what the bootstrap does, but I have no intuition about why I would make one choice or another.

Comment: You're using the specific pattern of same-ranks (singles, doubles, triples etc) that you get when you rank your two samples together.